# Running Time for CV.GLMNET

Tags: cross-validation

I am running a cv.glmnet model (Poisson Model for rates) in R:

**elasticnet_poisson_model <- cv.glmnet(x=design.x,y=y.,offset=log z.,family='poisson',alpha=elasticnet.alpha,standardize=FALSE,lambda=cust.lambda.series,penalty.factor=cust.pen,nfolds=5)**

*design.x is a sparse model matrix with around 20,000 columns and 2,80,000 rows.*

*cust.lambda.series <- base_lambda * 10^seq(from=0,to=-11,length.out=15)*

base lamnbda = 1,01,827 (Computed running a glmnet earlier which makes the coeeficients 0).

The model is running for 16 hours now without completing.

Did anyone face similar issue while working with cv.glmnet ? Any help on how to do it faster will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have the same issue. my X matrix is 350 MB and at first I wanted to apply CV for each value of alpha running from 0.1 to 0.9 in 0.05 intervals. After I saw that it has been 16-18 hours already and it didn't finish I have decided to run CV on a specific value of Alpha. Keeping fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

Is that 2.8M or 280,000 rows?

You might try fitting a single model without cross validation and see how long it takes, and extrapolate from there.